# Use a symbol for multiplication operator in sympy output in ipython notebook

Tags: python, latex, jupyter-notebook, sympy, mathjax

In ipython notebook I would like to be able to use a symbol (\times or \cdot) for the multiplication operator in the latex/mathjax output of an expression. Is this possible?

`sympy.latex()` has an option `mul_symbol` but I can't see how to use it to change the latex in an output cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math
from sympy import *
x1 = var('x_1')
x2 = var('x_2')
display(Math(latex(x1*x2,mul_symbol='dot')))
```

You can change `dot` to `times` or `ldot`.

This makes IPython render the latex using the desired symbol.

If you don't want that last line messing up all your code just define a function:

```
def Latex(expr):
    return display(Math(latex(expr,mul_symbol='dot')))
```

and now you can just use:

```
Latex(x1*x2)
```

Comment: You could create your own latex function that calls the sympy latex function with the option (or even calls the whole `display(Math(latex(...)))` bit ). See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, we need to add an option to `init_printing` that lets you specify options to the printer. Pull requests welcome!

Answer (score 7):

`init_printing()` has an argument `latex_printer`, so you can do something like

```
init_printing(latex_printer=lambda *args, **kwargs: latex(*args, mul_symbol='dot', **kwargs))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a function I keep in a library to create Latex printers:

```
def makeLatexPrinter(**localsets):
    def mylatex(expr,**settings):
        settings.update(localsets)
        return latex(expr,**settings)
    return mylatex
```

Then in my notebook I use:

```
init_printing(use_latex=True,latex_printer=makeLatexPrinter(mul_symbol='dot'))
```

It would be cleaner if `init_printing()` passed keyword arguments like `mul_symbol` through itself, though.